# In Flash Pro, how to get the Properties panel to expose the properties you define on your ActionScript class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm dabbling with game design and trying to create some characters for the game.  Right now I've just created a single MovieClip that contains a rectangle.  The MovieClip symbol extends a class that I've created in Flash Builder that implements the logic of a monster.  I can then drag an instance of this monster symbol from the library to the stage and the code works when I run the simulation.  So far, so good.

Now I want to create several monsters, all slightly different:

```
public class Monster extends MovieClip
{
    public var isFriendly:Boolean = true;
    public var strength:int = 10;
    public var catchPhrase:String = "Booyah!";

    public function Monster()
    {
    }
}
```

One way to do this is to write a new class for each monster that extends Monster and sets the properties I want in the constructor (I'd also have to create a unique symbol in the library for each of these variations too).  However, this seems to be overkill if my monsters only differ by their property values.

Looking at the Flash Professional use interface, I see that at the very bottom of the Properties panel is a section that looks like a small table headed by 'Properties/Value'.  Can I use this to somehow set the properties of my classes from within the Flash Professional UI?  I can't find any info on how this is used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.  The key is converting my symbol into a flash Component.

First I edited my ActionScript class to export the properties I wanted to set (including the Inspectable tag):

```
public class Monster
{
    private var _catchPhrase:String;

    public function Monster()
    {
    }

    public function get catchPhrase():String
    {
        return _catchPhrase;
    }

    [Inspectable(name = "catchPhrase", type = String, defaultValue = "Booyah!")]
    public function set catchPhrase(value:String):void
    {
        _catchPhrase = value;
    }

}
```

Then I right clicked on the Monster symbol in my library and selected 'Component Definition...'.  This brought up the Component Definition dialog.  I then entered the name of my ActionScript class in the Class field and clicked the checkmark to validate it.  Flash then automatically generated the properties I needed.

I also found this tutorial helpful:
http://redbjarne.wordpress.com/actionscript-3-0-custom-components-from-hell/